# How to setup network scanning for HP 3055 in Windows 7/Vista 64 bits?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, networking, scanner

Network scanning with HP 3055 works fine with XP, but I can't install it neither with Vista nor Windows 7 (both 64 bits OS).

Could anybody assist me with the issue?

Comment: Run the installer in Compatibility mode as suggested in the following link http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?objectID=c02096212

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can scan and send faxes using Windows 7 Virual PC / XP Mode. Just run it, install drivers/software and enjoy. No other ways to solve problem if you have x64.

Answer (score 2):

HP has failed to release any 64-bit network scanner drivers. for now, you can only use the HP 3055 as a printer with 64-bit operating systems.

having said that, scanning should be possible via the USB interface.

Answer (score 1):

Scanning is possible using the HP Laserjet 3055 with Windows 7 Home 64 bit, using the USB interface. Once you have installed the printer, Go to the START menu, open Devices and Printers, click on the FAX icon and go to the very top of the page, to the NEW SCAN tab. that will allow you to scan and then save the scan to whatever file you wish. If my experience is typical, documents take a *long* time to scan.

So far, their seems to be no network solution.

This solution is hardly acceptable, but it is better than nothing. I'm shocked that HP has failed to support its AIO users this way, up to this point.

Good luck

Comment: Thank, but I'm looking for network scanning.

Answer (score 1):

HP Laserjet 3055 do not have a Scanner Driver Compatible with Windows 7.

See the [List of all the available drivers](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareIndex.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodNameId=1140780&prodTypeId=18972&prodSeriesId=1161389&swLang=8&taskId=135&swEnvOID=4063#1130) that we can download